# My regular expression is still capturing a non-captured group

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regular expression:

`(?:^(?:X-Rcpt-To|X-MDRcpt-To|To): (?:[\<\'\"])?(.*?)(?:[\>\'\"])?$)`

And the following block of text:

`To: <test@somedomain.com>`

It captures the email that it's supposed to here: https://regex101.com/r/gQ1bV5/1

But when I implement this within my code, it still captures `>` etc at the end of the email address. (Returning `test@somedomain.com>`)

```
public string FindRealEmail()
{
    var filterRegex = new Regex("(?:^(?:X-Rcpt-To|X-MDRcpt-To|To): (?:[\\<\\\'\\\"])?(.*?)(?:[\\>\\\'\\\"])?$)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    var email = (filterRegex.IsMatch(Body) ? filterRegex.Match(Body).Groups[1].Value : EmailAddress).Replace("\r", "");
    return email;
}
```

Comment: Noncapturing groups still make up pstt of the match. Else, use lookarounds.

Comment: I'm not getting any results with this regex

Comment: So why is it **not** capturing `<` but still captures `>`. They are supposed to be non-capturing... @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: I will be only able to help more once I'm at my computer. I meant to type "make part of" in the above comment.

Comment: The point is that `.` matches `\r` in .NET regex. If you do not use `\r?` before `$`, the `[>'"]?` is expected before `\n` - but they are before `\r` in the real string, so `(.*?)` captures the `>` and `"` into itself. You already got a correct solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not really because of the last non-capturing group but the line endings.  If you handle the line feed at the end, the > isn't captured.

`(?:^(?:X-Rcpt-To|X-MDRcpt-To|To): (?:[\<\'\"])?(.*?)(?:[\>\'\"])?\r?$)`

If you don't need to capture certain sections, you can just omit the parentheses.  You don't have to escape the `<`, `'` & `"` characters either.

`^(?:X-Rcpt-To|X-MDRcpt-To|To): [<'"]?(.*?)[>'"]?\r?$`